# Unexpected token colon in HQL

Tags: hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate and am trying to do the following but I get `unexpected token: :` error. It must be a rookie error, since i'm a rookie. I've already populated the table with Vehicle class. This code works fine when I don't use named parameter. But I want to know why it's not working.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.dono.util.SessionManager;
import org.javabrains.dono.dto.cascade.Vehicle;

public class HQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session = SessionManager.configureSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    /*for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle.setVehicleName("Car no. "+i);
        session.save(vehicle);
    }*/
    String q="from :tabl";
    Query query= session.createQuery(q);
    query.setString("tabl", "Vehicle");
    query.setFirstResult(3);
    query.setMaxResults(2);
    List<Vehicle> vehicles= (List<Vehicle>) query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();    
    for (Iterator<Vehicle> i = vehicles.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Vehicle car = (Vehicle) i.next();
        System.out.println(car.getVehicleName());
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter is usually used within a where clause.

Wrong:

```
session.creteQuery("from :tabl");
```

Right:

```
session.createQuery("from Vehicle");
```

Using a parameter:

```
Query qry = session.createQuery("from Vehicle where id = :id");
qry.setParameter("id", yourId);
```